# Get only one element from URL using Jquery

Tags: jquery, innerhtml, indexof

I have url that goes like this

**http://wwww.example.com/eng/about/what**

I want to have new var like this in Jquery, that is working in IE8

`var lang ="eng"`;

And replace innerHTML of element, for now i have something like this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var lang = "ENG";
        $(".dropdown-toggle").html(lang + "<b class='caret'></b>");

    });'
```

The problem is that var eng can we somethin else, i have tried with indexOF, but no luck?
And if there is no value inside i must use default

```
var lang = "eng";
```

EDITED

For now we have made it to this

$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;
    var arr = url.split("/");
    var lang = (arr[1] != undefined) ? arr[1] : "en";

});

The problem is on default loading of index page, it means, what some one get on home page
Hi only gets

```
http://wwww.example.com/
```

But sometime he gets

```
http://wwww.example.com/fr
```

or something else depends on language

Comment: Is URL `http://wwww.example.com/about/what` also possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your url structure is same, you can use this;

```
var url = "http://wwww.example.com";
//var url = "http://wwww.example.com/fr/about/what";
var arr = url.split("/");
var lang = (arr[3] != undefined && (arr[3].length == 2 || arr[3] == "eng") ) ? arr[3]: "eng";
```

Here is a working demo: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/RNnsk/5/)**

Comment: For now it is owrking ok, but the problem is var url, this is now hardcoded, i need that to get from url, not to be hard hoded, but this is good working example

Comment: @Schneider where is this url you want to get from form or browser url?

Comment: It is in var url  i want to get from browser url

Comment: @dfsq I think user assumes url structure will remain same. Maybe double check will be good for fetched lang value

Comment: @Schneider what do you mean with var url? I mean you want to get url from browser?

Comment: Yes, i want to get url from browser

Comment: I see mate, but still now working :( This is working ok          var url = window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
        var arr = url.split("/");
        var lang = (arr[1] != undefined) ? arr[1] : "en";
        alert(lang); But on homepage like www.example.com it is not working ok :(

Comment: but I have added protocol part. Use this `var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;` . It is in my answer also

Comment: How do you want to act when user enters `http://wwww.example.com/` ? It should be eng? By the way, you didnt use my latest code. You have forgot to add protocol part

Comment: Yes, i want to react like ENG

Comment: Yes i saw that, but for now i am using localhost

Comment: You can check lang value like if it is 2 length string, it is language(One exception for only eng. It is 3 but it would be better if you use lang values as 2 length chars like en, fr, de,it). See my updated demo and answer

Comment: Nice, but i have problem, what if i have /fr or something else, that does not work?

Comment: What do you mean that doesnt work? It works with /fr

Comment: Yes, but what if i dont have /fr ? only have http://www.example.com that i have to have default value En

Comment: Yes that time, it will act as eng as you said. It is also work in demo

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
var lang = location.pathname.match(/^\/(.+?)\//)[1];
```

For example if current URL is `http://wwww.example.com/fr/about/what` lang will be `fr`.

Comment: Nice, but i want ot have default value eng if i dont have nothing in url?

Answer (score 0):

if the URL is http://wwww.example.com/eng/about/what then,

```
document.URL.split("/")[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of plugin https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl or http://www.kevinleary.net/jquery-parse-url/ to get query string params and uri segments.